# Alter 2 columns in single SQL statement

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
           WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'TEMPTABLE')
BEGIN
    alter table TEMPTABLE alter column [Column1] [nvarchar](25) null;
    alter table TEMPTABLE alter column [Column2] [nvarchar](25) null;
END
```

This is what I am using currently.

How I can alter 2 columns in a single statement.Is it possible.?

If yes . Please provide the solution

Thanks

Comment: Using mysql or other RDBMS?

Comment: Check my answer in MySQL

Comment: it is better to do one by one rather then go by single statement

Comment: Single query fire is faster than making multiple. I think. @Jonathan And, DDL statements are not frequently used. it is only used when you want to change Database Schema. so, There is not much important to call single statement or multiple.

Comment: yeah offcourse minimal will be more exciting but it will not be the best practice

Comment: Hi All . I know multiple statement is recommended. I would be excited if something is available like this in single statement. Just for curiosity I want to know

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CHANGE` in your `ALTER` statement for multiple column modify separated by commas `(,)`.

e.g. (Database Type: MySQL)

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id INT (11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  fname VARCHAR (20),
  lname VARCHAR (20),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ;

ALTER TABLE test 
CHANGE fname fname VARCHAR(35),
CHANGE lname lname VARCHAR(40);

DESC test;
```

Comment: I forgot to mention.. I need it in SQL Server 2008

Comment: I am checking for SQL Server

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx
Seems like no option available to ALTER multiple column in SQL Server. as MySQL Does.

If you try to modify multiple gives you an error `Incorrect syntax near ','.`

e.g. `ALTER TABLE test
 ALTER COLUMN fname NVARCHAR,
    ALTER COLUMN lname NVARCHAR;`

Can Drop multiple columns.